# Running Ajax From HTML list Issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run Ajax on a web application which is suppose to list associated data with HTML List from MySQL database using jQuery and PHP.I have two tables in MySQL database called Item and Items as below:

[image]

and I have to PHP file called index.php and result.php as:
================================================================== index.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
   {
     die('Unable to connect!');
   }
  else{
$query = 'SELECT * FROM items';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    ?>  
        <p>
            Select a language
            <ul id="item">
      <?php     
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>      
<li><div id="selectLanguage"><?php echo $row['item']; ?></div></li>     
<?php           
        }
 ?>
            </ul>
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  <?php
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No records found!';
    }
    $result->close();
}
else 
{
    echo 'Error in query: $query. '.$mysqli->error;
}
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#selectLanguage').click(function()
            {
            alert("hello");
                if($(this).val() == '') return;
                $.get(
                    'results.php',
                    { id : $(this).val() },
                    function(data)
                    {
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result.php is
====================================================================== result.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');
$resultStr = '';
 $query = 'SELECT type FROM item where name='.$_GET['item'];
 if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
 {
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    $resultStr.='<ul>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $resultStr.= '<li><strong>'.$row['id'].'</strong> - '.$row['type'];
    '</li>';
    }
    $resultStr.= '</ul>';
}
else
{
    $resultStr = 'Nothing found';
}
     }
    echo $resultStr;
    ?>
```

now the first part(index.php) is rendering the list base on the items table but I can't click at the second or third item besides none of them not returning any values to the page.
Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the selectLanguage div id multiple times.  You should use a class instead of an id.  Also.  the val() is null.  You should use html() instead.

looks like in result.php you're populating the list by parameter 'item'
when in your jquery ajax function you're passing the parameter as 'id'

change one of those and you should be good.

Comment: Hi Bluetoft, Thanks for your perfect hints. I change the id to class selector and the index.php is working fine now.I also change the val() to html() function but can you please let me know why we should do this? in results.php I update the .$_GET['item']; to .$_GET['id']; but this is not displaying anything on the page! not even error message!

Comment: @user1760110 I'm not a php dev... I was theinking the $_Get['item'] function was how you got access to the http request object.  Anyway... Just make sure you're accessing the correct request parameter in your php file.

Comment: well I confused is there anybody to help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Change Your index.php file as :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');
   if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
   {
     die('Unable to connect!');
   }
  else{
$query = 'SELECT * FROM items';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
    ?>  
        <p>
            Select a language
            <ul id="item">
      <?php     
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>      
<li><div id="selectLanguage<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['item']; ?></div></li>


   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#selectLanguage<?php echo $row['id']; ?>').click(function()
            {
            //alert("hello");

                $.ajax({
                      type : 'POST',
                      url : 'result.php',

                     data: {
                     id : <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
                       },
                      success : function(data){

                         $('#result').html(data);
}

                });


            });
        });
    </script>

<?php           
        }
 ?>
            </ul>
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
  <?php
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'No records found!';
    }
    $result->close();
}
else 
{
    echo 'Error in query: $query. '.$mysqli->error;
}
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Vikas sorrry I didn't see you comment erliear , Thanks for code but now I am getting this error at page:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\wamp\www\RumAiax_List\results.php on line 6

Comment: and this what I have in line 6 if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))

Comment: sorry for mistake I figure out why it was happening(I forget to terminate the statement)now I am not getting that error but after clicking on listed item this error shows up: **Notice: Undefined index: item in C:\wamp\www\Test_List\results.php on line 4**